# How to select the max number from a table column, assign to a variable, and increment by 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and MySQL. In my database I have a table called invoice. There's an id column that auto increments and a invoice_num column (and other columns). After I connect to the database I want to:

1. Get the currently highest number in the invoice_num column (of the invoice table)
2. Assign that value to a variable and increment by 1
3. Echo the new value to the screen

something like...

```
$highNum = mysql_query("SELECT invoice_num FROM INVOICE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";);
$highNum = $highNum++;
echo "Use Invoice Number:" .$highNum. "\n";
```

But I don't know the proper syntax.

Aside 1: It would be easier to ditch the id and just auto-increment the invoice_num column.  However I'd like the number to be longer than single digits and auto_increment starts with 1...2...3...etc. I know that if I alter the table I could start with a higher number like 100000 but the bash shell we are assigned will not allow students to alter a table.
Aside 2: currently invoice_num is an int.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$highNum = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(invoice_num) FROM INVOICE";);
$highNum = $highNum++;
echo "Use Invoice Number:" .$highNum. "\n";
```

I also don't know PHP syntax, but your query will be as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
$highnum = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(invoice_num) FROM INVOICE");
echo "Use Invoice Number:" .$highNum++. "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for getting the largest invoice number, and then use the increment variable as presented there

```
$highNum = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(invoice_num) FROM INVOICE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MYSQL's `MAX()` function to get the highest invoice_num in the database table.

And rather than `mysql_*` functions use `mysqli_*'s` instead or `PDO's` since `mysql_*` is already deprecated in PHP **5.5.0**, and was removed in **PHP 7.0.0.**

**Updated Code:**

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT MAX(invoice_num) as highNum FROM INVOICE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$highNum = $row['highNum']++;
echo "Use Invoice Number:" .$highNum. "\n";
```